# Unordered map containing a graph node as the key

Tags: c++, hashmap

I am working on implementing dijsktra's algorithm for traversing a graph and I have hit a small roadblock.

```
class Node{

private:
int id = -1;
unordered_map<Node*, int> edges;

};
```

As you can see each node in the graph contains an int for an id as well as an unordered map containing a node* as the key value and the edge length as the underlying data. The issue i'm having is I do not know what the best way to hash these id's.

Id's will be read in from a file and numbered in order. What is the best way to hash these id's without having many collisions?

EDIT: I currently am just hashing in such a way that returns the id mod edges.size() but I don't believe this to be the best way.

Comment: Take a look at the hash used by `std::pair`, which combines the hashes for the two items it holds, or for `std::tuple`.  For `edges` you can walk thru it and build a hash value for the map based solely on the key (`Node`) in each entry.

Comment: Also, I suggest avoiding naked pointers, use smart pointers instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't even bother with the `% edges.size()`. The unordered_map itself will already perform a `% this -> _Table.size()`.

Note that for sparsely connected graphs (say < 8 edges/node) a simple `std::vector<std::pair<Node*,int>>` is probably more efficient.